# What are the inf and sup of the set $S=\{r \in \mathbb{Q} : r^2 < 2 \}$

Tags: real-analysis

Good morning, I am reviewing possible test questions for my first analysis exam and I want to check to make sure that I am thinking about this correctly.

Let $S=\{r \in \mathbb{Q} : r^2 < 2 \}$  I know that the sup S does not exists, but is there an infimum? I am thinking that there isn't due to the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, that you can always find some other rational number that is closer and closer to $0$.

Comment: Isn't $0$ a rational number?

Comment: Note $(-1)^2 < 2$. The infimum is $-\sqrt{2}$, just like the supremum is $\sqrt{2}$ (let's look at it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so the existence is unproblematic).

Comment: Moreover, when you say "does not exist", do you mean "is not in the set" - these are different things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider $S$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$, this is just $S=(-\sqrt{2},+\sqrt{2})\cap\mathbb Q$ and thus $\inf S = -\sqrt 2$ and $\sup s=+\sqrt 2$.

If you consider $S$ as a subset of $\mathbb Q$, both infimum and supremum don't exist, roughly speaking because there's always another rational between $q\in \mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt{2}$. If you are looking for a rigorous proof that $\sup S$ does not exists in $\mathbb Q$, let me know.

Comment: As a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ $S=(-\sqrt2,\sqrt2)\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You are correct, I fixed that in my answer.

Comment: That is sufficient, I'm having pre-test jitters where I forget everything..

Answer (score 1):

Since you speaking about $\sup$ and $\inf$, rather than about $\max$ and $\min$, you must be considering $S$ as a subset of some larger set and whether or not $S$ has a supremum or an infimum depends on this larger set.

If this larger set is ${\mathbb Q}$, then $S$ has neither a supremum nor an infimum (in ${\mathbb Q}$).

If this larger set is ${\mathbb R}$, then $S$ does have both a supremum and an infimum (in $\mathbb R$), namely, respectively $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$.